# An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: Only a type can be imported. sito.progettoweb resolves to a package

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

I need help!

I am trying to import a java class into some jsp files. `eclipse` compiles correctly, but when I start the program I get this error message:

```
Type Exception Report
Message Unable to compile class for JSP:
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
Exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: [14] in the generated java file: [C:\xampp\tomcat\work\Catalina\localhost\examples\org\apache\jsp\webproject\WebContent\index_jsp.java]
Only a type can be imported. sito.progettoweb resolves to a package

Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:103)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:366)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:536)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:379)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:354)
    org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:341)
    org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:660)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Comment: Is the message wrong?

Comment: as the others asked, you should address the error message. I think you homed in on the key part of the message: "Only a type can be imported". I don't know that package sito.progrettoweb, can you help clarify what is a package there and what is a class?

Comment: this package contains a java class 
which contains several functions (for example functions for connecting to the database located in mysql)